# binding class files in the jar file not generated by netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

When i clean and build my project using netbeans , though it makes the jar file of the project but it doesn't keep those files that i myself kept in the project folder. That includes some class files,a music file. What is the reason for this ? How do i do this ? I want to keep some class files not generated by the netbeans and also the music file.

Comment: So what you are asking is, how to get some custom lies into the JAR built by NetBeans?

Comment: @ Perception yes. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for this ?  default Netbeans build.xml don't include other lib files.

If you look the dist folder you can see a lib folder too. This is your lib folder. If your lib files is in the classpath you jar run on every where if not your file look ./lib/*.jar

You can change your project to ant project or maven project and change your manifest and other files.